# How to integrate my Umbraco site with Worldpay

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco, worldpay

I need to connect my Umbraco website to my Worldpay account.
I found few articles about this but as it's all new to me I need a simple and straightforward sample.
I followed this [Article](http://www.publicvoid.dk/SetupUCommerceToIncludeRBSWorldPayAsAPaymentMethod.aspx) but yet don't know how to connect my User Controls (payment forms) to world pay.

Any helps would be appreciated.

@Digbyswift: I have tried your solution and still not success! 
 I would be appreciated if you could take a look and let me know what is the problem in my code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LoadForm.ascx.cs" Inherits="BInstitute.usercontrols.LoadForm" %>

<form action="https://secure-test.worldpay.com/wcc/purchase" name="BuyForm" method="POST" >
<input type="hidden" name="instId"  value= "<% = this.instId %>" ><!-- The "instId" value "211616" should be replaced with the Merchant's own installation Id -->
<input type="hidden" name="cartId" value="abc123"  ><!-- This is a unique identifier for merchants use. Example: PRODUCT123 -->
<input type="hidden" name="currency" value="GBP" ><!-- Choose appropriate currency that you would like to use -->
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<% = this.amount %>">
<input type="hidden" name="desc" value="<% = this.desc %>" >
<input type="hidden" name="testMode" value="100"  >
<div id="MembershipForm" runat="server" visible="False">


    <table>
       <tr>
            <td width="25%" >
                <asp:Label ID="lblMembershipSurname" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td >
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMembershipSurname" runat="server" Class="textblock"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td width="25%" >
                <asp:Label ID="lblMembershipAddressLine1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td >
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMembershipAddressLine1" runat="server" Class="textblock"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="25%" >
                <asp:Label ID="lblMembershipAddressLine2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td >
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMembershipAddressLine2" runat="server" Class="textblock"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td width="25%" >
                <asp:Button ID="btnMembershipSubmit" runat="server"  PostBackUrl="https://secure-test.worldpay.com/wcc/purchase" Class="btn_submit"/>
            </td>
            <td >
                &nbsp;</td>

        </tr>
        </table>

</div>

</form>
```

And the backend source code is:

```
public partial class LoadForm : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        private string _instId = "288499";
        private string _cartId = "Test";
        private string _currency = "GBP";
        private string _testMode = "100";
        private string _amount = "10";
        private string _desc = "testDesc";

        public string desc
        {
            get { return _desc; }
            set { _desc = value; }
        }

        public string amount
        {
            get { return _amount; }
            set { _amount = value; }
        }

        public string instId
        {
            get { return _instId; }
            set { _instId = value; }
        }

        public string cartId
        {
            get { return _cartId; }
            set { _cartId = value; }
        }

        public string currency
        {
            get { return _currency; }
            set { _currency = value; }
        }

        public string testMode
        {
            get { return _testMode; }
            set { _testMode = value; }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you should be considering is how would you *usually* connect WorldPay to a .Net website. The fact that your site is Umbraco-based needn't complicate things.

Find a couple of articles describing integration into a *standard* .Net website and see if those approaches will work with your website. The only complicating factor might be defining a "callback" page, but then at worst you could just use a hard-coded URL.

Many questions like this assume that Umbraco complicates otherwise well-documented tasks. But generally an Umbraco site is still just user controls and masterpages or views and actions.

If you want to make the Worldpay configuration editable within Umbraco, that is another question completely.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
Please take a look at this article: 
http://www.worldpay.com/support/kb/bg/htmlredirect/rhtml5206.html
There is sample HTML codes for this. But the problem is that Umbraco changes the ID of input items automatically and therefore Worldpay can not recognize the values in these hidden input items (instId, cartId, etc)

Any suggestions for that?

Comment: Why would Umbraco change the IDs? I think you mean that *.Net* changes the ID values because you are using .Net controls in a usercontrol possibly. You can get round this by using `ClientIDMode="Static"` on your controls provided you are using .Net 4. If not, just use static markup and render the values of the field using bindings, e.g. `<input type="hidden" name="instId" value="<% =    this.WorldPayId %>">`

Comment: Sorry and Yes I meant .Net 
I tried your solution as well. but still see the error page. I have updated the question with my code. Could you please help me through this?

Comment: I found the problem.
The action value for main Form should be changed into https://secure-test.worldpay.com/wcc/purchase

Thanks DigbySwift.